# Android Relative Layout circular dependencies error

Tags: android, layout

Hi im trying to create a custom layout but i'm struggling to get it to work properly i'm getting an error "circluar dependencies cannot exist in Relative layout"

heres what im trying to acheive in termas of layout and then fill each text field with data.

```
date                number
name   score - score  name
scorers              scorers
```

heres my attempt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/HomeScore"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:text="-"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AwayTeam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HomeTeam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/HomeScore"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Attendance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/AwayTeam"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/HomeScore"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Division"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/HomeScore"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AwayScore"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView04"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HomeScore"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TextView04"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

heres the error

```
06-06 14:42:44.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1167): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
06-06 14:42:44.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1272)
06-06 14:42:44.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:281)
06-06 14:42:44.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:303)
06-06 14:42:44.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8526)
06-06 14:42:44.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1153)
06-06 14:42:44.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1266)
06-06 14:42:44.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
06-06 14:42:44.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8526)
06-06 14:42:44.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3224)
06-06 14:42:44.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
06-06 14:42:44.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.widget.TableLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(TableLayout.java:456)
06-06 14:42:44.348: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you have a few problems here:

1. `TextView04` declares `android:layout_below="@+id/HomeScore"` and `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`, which conflict
2. `AwayTeam` declares `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView04"` and `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"`, which conflict
3. `HomeTeam` declares `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView04"` and `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"`, which conflict
4. `AwayScore` declares `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView04"` and `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"`, which conflict

As Samir points out, at least one of your circular dependencies is between `TextView04` and `HomeScore`. `TextView04` says it is to be below `HomeScore`, and `HomeScore` says its bottom is aligned with the bottom of `TextView04`. However, some of the other ones I note above may also create circular dependencies. Ensure that two widgets do not try to constrain on each other on the same axis (as in `TextView04` and `HomeScore`).

Comment: "Ensure that each widget only constrains itself once in each axis "  Isn't it common to constrain between two views in an axis if you want to fill the area between them?

Comment: @Barak: You are right -- the story is more complex than I indicated. I removed that passage from my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Remove `android:layout_below="@+id/HomeScore"` from first `TextView` in your layout it creates circular dependencies.

> Why ?

Because you set `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"` in Textview whose id is 
`android:id="@+id/HomeScore"`.and first Textview(TextView04) have also `android:layout_below="@+id/HomeScore"`.

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:text="-"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: thank you - just for learning purposes what is a circular depency

Answer (score 1):

You have a small mistake that might be the reason:

When you reference to another id, don't use `@+id/...` just `@id/...`. So everywhere except the `android:id` attribute the `+` must be removed.

After you have done that you might get some warnings that point to the possible error!

Comment: That is incorrect. The *first occurrence* of an ID gets the `+`, even if that occurs before the `android:id`. For example, see: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Containers/Relative/res/layout/main.xml

Comment: `RelativeLayout` has supported forward-references like this for nearly three years: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/ui-framework-changes-in-android-16.html

Comment: ok thank you. That is the disadvantage of early adopters. You can't keep up with all changes :)