# RelativeLayout wrap_content width, circular dependency

Tags: android, width, android-relativelayout

Want to design a custom marker-baloon for the new Google Maps v2 API for Android. I have overridden getInfoContents but my now the layout takes the full width of the screen with ym custom design. I want it to wrap around the text with a max width.

I have found my problem after reading online, its probably that I have circular dependency in the RelativeLayout which is not permitted. But then how would I move the textfield "place" to the right of the layout, in line with the title but on the right side?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingBottom="2sp"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:paddingTop="1sp"
        android:textColor="@color/list_item_title_color"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"sa
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:paddingBottom="3sp"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:paddingRight="5sp"
        android:textColor="@color/list_item_text_color"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="5sp"
        android:paddingTop="1sp"
        android:textColor="@color/list_item_date_color"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/icons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/place"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="2sp"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:paddingRight="5sp" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where's the circular dependency?

Comment: If I understand it correctly it is in 'android:layout_alignParentRight="true"'.

Comment: No that shouldn't cause a circular dependency, it's not constrained by anything else as you have it above. See here for some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916892/android-relative-layout-circular-dependencies-error

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title"
```

to your place textview?

EDIT:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/leftLayout"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingBottom="2sp"
    android:paddingLeft="5sp"
    android:paddingTop="1sp"
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_title_color"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"sa
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:paddingBottom="3sp"
    android:paddingLeft="5sp"
    android:paddingRight="5sp"
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_text_color"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/icons"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/place"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="2sp"
    android:paddingLeft="5sp"
    android:paddingRight="5sp" >
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/leftLayout"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="5sp"
        android:paddingTop="1sp"
        android:textColor="@color/list_item_date_color"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here, try this, but it's not tested.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that just places it to the right of the title, but I want it all the way to the right.
'|..................|
|Title        Place|
|Text         icons|  <- the icons are in the linearLayout.
|..................|'

Comment: Then you can wrap your entire RelativeLayout with another RelativeLayout and put yout place textview in this outer layout. Then set toRightOf="@id/leftLayout" (leftLayout is id of your existing RelativeLayout).

Comment: I am trying different settings but the 'place' and 'title' overlaps each other. They are both still on the left side.

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe this will work for you as you want.

Comment: Thats closer but I still can not find it out how to make it look right/work. This is how I want it to be witouth the overlapping and the overly to big window. This is from the code I posted in the question. http://i559.photobucket.com/albums/ss36/TutenStain/Screenshot_2013-02-11-21-54-50_zps4c3ec2b6.png

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand, you should be able to wrap the "title, place, and text" in a `linearlayout`

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/textLL
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
//textViews
</LinearLayout>
```

now use

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textLL"
```

in your "icons" layout. Or is this not what you want?

Comment: Almost, But I want it like this. Thanks for your reply. http://i559.photobucket.com/albums/ss36/TutenStain/Screenshot_2013-02-11-21-54-50_zps4c3ec2b6.png

Comment: If "place" goes next to "title" then put those two in the `LinearLayout` with `orientation='horizontal'` then "text" aligned below that `LinearLayout`