# need help in my application has stopped working

Tags: android

hi guys i tried to make a small space between a statement and who said it and some helped me by adding `android:layout` given below-

and this is my result

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
  android:padding="6dip" >


<TextView

android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/secondLine"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="@string/state1"
android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/secondLine"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="26dip"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="@string/sayer1"
android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

now after i added it when i test it out it just crashes and doesnt work i hope you can help me

Comment: Post your logcat, or what error you are getting. also show your activity.java code...

Answer (score 2):

There is ciruclar dependency in the layout. yOu have to remove layout_below.

[Android Relative Layout circular dependencies error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916892/android-relative-layout-circular-dependencies-error)

Comment: Can you explain the question to others?

Answer (score 0):

full xml will be like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
  android:padding="6dip" >


<TextView

android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/secondLine"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="@string/state1"
android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/secondLine"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="26dip"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="@string/sayer1"
android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistakes :
Inside your first textview there is a : android:layout_above="@+id/secondLine", i should have been "@id" and not "@+id" but i wouldn't work either since the secondLine is not put before but after, it would have tell you that there is no secondLine.
Layout_below is well enough on the second textview.

```
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
 android:padding="6dip" >

         <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:text="@string/state1"
          android:textSize="16sp" />

         <TextView
          android:id="@+id/secondLine"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="26dip"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
          android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
          android:ellipsize="marquee"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:text="@string/sayer1"
          android:textSize="12sp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```