# why is "Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout" this happening?

Tags: android

I am making a chat application, but what is happening when the keyboard appears it hides my edit text but when I shift my layout, in which I have edit text to layout_below to upper relative layout having id "@+id/Rl_ChatLayout", it is giving me an `IllegalStateException`

I have tried to figure it out but I couldn't found  any help 
And studied the following link

[Android Relative Layout circular dependencies error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916892/android-relative-layout-circular-dependencies-error)

Here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/TopLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_back"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back_icon_2x"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Image"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_back">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/recUserImg"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/image_circle_shape"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <com.dd.sproutchat.customcontrols.MLRoundedImageView
                    android:id="@+id/userImg"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_Search"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Image"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="start"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtOnlineStatus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_Menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/menu_icon_2x"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_Search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_icon_2x" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Rl_line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TopLayout"
            android:background="@color/chat_border"></RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Rl_Options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Rl_line"
            android:background="@color/chat_options_bg">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_Home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/home_btn_active_2x" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_SproutesList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/chat_btn_2x" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_Note"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/note_btn_2x" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Rl_line2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Rl_Options"
            android:background="@color/chat_border"></RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Rl_ChatLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/Rl_MessageLayout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Rl_line2">

            <!-- android:background="@drawable/chat_bg_2x" -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Btn_Chats"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/count"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_Sortby"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/icon_sortby_sprout_2x" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_AddSprout"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_Sortby"
                        android:weightSum="2">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_AllSprouts"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
                            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                            android:paddingRight="25dp"
                            android:paddingTop="3dp"
                            android:text="@string/AllSprouts"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_AllFavorites"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/btn_blank"
                            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                            android:paddingRight="15dp"
                            android:paddingTop="3dp"
                            android:text="@string/AllFavorites"
                            android:textColor="@color/grey_start" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/btn_AddSprout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/icon_add_sprout_2x" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/noteLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <EditText

                        android:id="@+id/searchBar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton4" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton5"
                        android:background="@drawable/sort" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/add" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/Lv_Chat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/Btn_Chats"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:stackFromBottom="true"
                android:transcriptMode="normal"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Rl_MessageLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Rl_ChatLayout"
            android:background="@color/chat_screen_bottom">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_Attachment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/attachment_icon_white_2x" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_Send"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_Attachment"
                android:background="@drawable/txt_field"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                    />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_Send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_send_white_2x" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this my log cat

```
08-25 16:48:07.400    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/﹕ appName=com.dd.sproutchat, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
08-25 16:48:07.400    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/﹕ 0
08-25 16:48:07.470    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Profile pic boolean is true
08-25 16:48:07.471    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Path already exist
08-25 16:48:07.471    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Path is /storage/sdcard0/SproutChat/Profile Pictures
08-25 16:48:07.499    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Profile pic boolean is true
08-25 16:48:07.499    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Path already exist
08-25 16:48:07.499    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Path is /storage/sdcard0/SproutChat/Profile Pictures
08-25 16:48:07.511    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Profile pic boolean is true
08-25 16:48:07.511    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Path already exist
08-25 16:48:07.511    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Path is /storage/sdcard0/SproutChat/Profile Pictures
08-25 16:48:07.552    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Profile pic boolean is true
08-25 16:48:07.552    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Path already exist
08-25 16:48:07.552    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Path is /storage/sdcard0/SproutChat/Profile Pictures
08-25 16:48:07.660    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Profile pic boolean is true
08-25 16:48:07.660    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Path already exist
08-25 16:48:07.660    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Path is /storage/sdcard0/SproutChat/Profile Pictures
08-25 16:48:07.711    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Profile pic boolean is true
08-25 16:48:07.711    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Path already exist
08-25 16:48:07.711    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Path is /storage/sdcard0/SproutChat/Profile Pictures
08-25 16:48:07.848    2725-2744/com.dd.sproutchat E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x6138a568 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x60efb940 arg=0x0
08-25 16:48:07.848    2725-2744/com.dd.sproutchat E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x6138a568 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
08-25 16:48:08.669    2725-2797/com.dd.sproutchat E/SignalR Status﹕ Connected Successfuly
08-25 16:48:09.003    2725-2744/com.dd.sproutchat E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x613880e0 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x60efb940 arg=0x0
08-25 16:48:09.003    2725-2744/com.dd.sproutchat E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x613880e0 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
08-25 16:48:09.631    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/SproutChat﹕ Size After Added::1
08-25 16:48:09.866    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Profile pic boolean is true
08-25 16:48:09.867    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Path already exist
08-25 16:48:09.867    2725-2725/com.dd.sproutchat E/testing﹕ Path is /storage/sdcard0/SproutChat/Profile Pictures
08-25 16:48:10.725    2725-2752/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x6318dfb8 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x61385940 arg=0x0
08-25 16:48:10.726    2725-2752/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x6318dfb8 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
08-25 16:48:10.836    2725-2725/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dd.sproutchat, PID: 2725
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1796)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:390)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:406)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16842)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:824)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:500)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16842)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16842)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16842)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2332)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16842)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2246)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1312)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1509)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5304)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 16:48:11.408    2725-2754/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x614a4c20 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x615d8940 arg=0x0
08-25 16:48:11.408    2725-2754/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x614a4c20 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is because of cyclic reference between the views present in RelativeLayout.

In xml,

Rl_MessageLayout and Rl_ChatLayout are relatively referring to each other.  So the layout is not able to position both the views.

Solution would be remove on relation and arrange your view with other attributes.

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Rl_ChatLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/Rl_MessageLayout" //remove this line
            android:layout_below="@+id/Rl_line2">
```

Comment: but one more problem I can see after removing the line you mentioned above now I am not able see my relative layout having id "android:id="@+id/Rl_MessageLayout""

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused because there is a circular reference in your layout parameters.

For example say `A`, `B` and `C` are views in your layout XML and that `A` references `B` and references `C`. In that scenario `C` can't reference `A` because of a circular dependency.

Which basically means, when you reference a view (like this)

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/Image"
     ...
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_back">
```

You **cannot** then reference `@+id/Image` in the `btn_back` view. Somewhere in your layout, something similar is happening.

Edit: There is a circular reference in `Rl_MessageLayout` and `Rl_ChatLayout` as they reference each other. You will need to remove this as you do not need to specify that something is `android:layout_below` a view if you have already specified elsewhere in the *other* view that it is `android:layout_above` the view (and vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:layout_above="@+id/Rl_MessageLayout"` from `android:id="@+id/Rl_ChatLayout"` it is causing a circular dependancy with the 'Rl_MessageLayout'.

This is becuase the 'Rl_MessageLayout' indicates that 'Rl_CharLayout' is `android:layout_above` and `Rl_CharLayout` indicates the `Rl_MessageLayout` is `android:layout_below`.  As both of these are referring to each other it becomes a cyclic reference.