# Can't get my Button view to appear in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

In the code below (A custom list item) the Button view is not visible, it's like the ImageView takes all the place and not allow it to appear, how should I modify the code to make it appears at the bottom and rest of the space to be fore the ImageView?

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/inner_container_layout" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow">

        <!-- Title -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"/>

        <!--  Sub Title -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sub_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"/>

        <!-- Ad thumbnail -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cover"
            android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sub_title"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cover"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Button"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just align your `Button` to your parent bottom and your `ImageView` above your `Button`. Something like this,

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/inner_container_layout" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow">

        <!-- Title -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"/>

        <!--  Sub Title -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sub_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"/>

        <!-- Ad thumbnail -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cover"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sub_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Button"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help you..!!

Comment: For sorry at run time it gave me this error:                                                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

Comment: are you sure you are using the exact code I posted?

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I just had to remove                 android:layout_below="@+id/cover" from <Button> to avoid the error I mentioned in the comment.

Comment: This reference helped me to fix the error, still you have the credit to get it worked as I wanted to be ... Again thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916892/android-relative-layout-circular-dependencies-error

Comment: well if you look into the xml I provided , there was no such thing, I think you only added the extra code without removing the existing dependencies instead of simply replacing with my. Anyways I am glad you are able to trace the issue by your own. keep going :)